# How to pass an array from local storage to a flask view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

So my flask app is basically a restaurant website and it has two pages , the first one is where the user can pick their desired menu items (menu page) and the second page is for the user to fill in the form with their detail (order details page). In the menu page you will find the menu items that on click the item will show up in the MY ORDER section that is also in the menu page, i made it in javascript so the menu order will be saved to localStorage as an array of objects and gave it the name of shoppingMenu. What i am having an issue with: how do i validate that the shoppingMenu has at least one object(not null) in it before the user can go to the order details page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an if statement

```
if(showMenu != null){allow user to continue}
```

or even `if(showMenu != []){}`
because your showmenu would be empty, which would probably be more accurate.
Unless you initially set your showMenu to null, then the first example would be best.

Comment: What exactly is allow user to continue?

Comment: That was your code. Whatever you have that takes the user to the order_details page. Its just adding a conditional statement to validate before moving on to the next part of your application

Comment: Thank you @hunter i will try disabling  the submit button that leads to the order details page in case the shoppingMenu is null .

Comment: That will work and is easy to implement. onclick= validate() and then in validate check if shoppingmenu is null and if it is you could popup a message in red asking to add items to continue. I do believe I answered your question though. Can I get my check mark?

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` uses Strings to save the data, i.e., you always have to consider JavaScript String logic when reasoning on `null` vs. `undefined`, etc.

The `getItem(key)` method must return the current value associated with the given key. If the given key does not exist in the list associated with the object then this method must return `null`.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("shoppingMenu") !== null) {
    // do stuff
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is do stuff? That is what i am having an issue with

Comment: the do stuff is where you put the logic to take the user to the order details page

Comment: thanks a lot i am planning on disabling the submit button in case the shoppingMenu is null. You ispired me guys, thanks a lot